# Setting up a record in typescript using keyof typeof

Tags: javascript, typescript, record

I've set up an object with my enum-like times of das as follows and I'm trying to make the correct type for a record based on these entries.

```
export const TIMEOFDAY = {
    FirstLight: 'First Light',
    Morning: 'Morning',
    Antemeridiem: 'Antemeridiem',
    Zenith: 'Zenith',
    Postmeridiem: 'Postmeridiem',
    Evening: 'Evening',
    LastLight: 'Last Light',
    Night: 'Night',
}
```

When I try to set up the record, it tells me that basically all the keys are missing in my record entries. It seems TS can't see that I'm referencing them via `TIMEOFDAY.FirstLight` as shown below.

```
type TimeOfDayData = {
    phase: number
    hours: number
    lux: number
    temperature: number
}

type TimeOfDayDataRecord = Record<keyof typeof TIMEOFDAY, TimeOfDayData>

const TIMEOFDAYDATA: TimeOfDayDataRecord = {
    [TIMEOFDAY.FirstLight]: /*   */ { phase: 1, temperature: 10, hours: 5, lux: 1 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Morning]: /*      */ { phase: 2, temperature: 23, hours: 8, lux: 100 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Antemeridiem]: /* */ { phase: 3, temperature: 42, hours: 13, lux: 300 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Zenith]: /*       */ { phase: 4, temperature: 55, hours: 16, lux: 500 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Postmeridiem]: /* */ { phase: 3, temperature: 48, hours: 22, lux: 300 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Evening]: /*      */ { phase: 2, temperature: 32, hours: 25, lux: 100 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.LastLight]: /*    */ { phase: 1, temperature: 15, hours: 30, lux: 1 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Night]: /*        */ { phase: 0, temperature: -10, hours: 33, lux: 0 },
}
```

I'm seeing the following error:

`Type '{ [x: string]: { phase: number; temperature: number; hours: number; lux: number; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TimeOfDayDataRecord': Morning, Antemeridiem, Zenith, Postmeridiem, and 4 more.ts(2740)`

Any ideas how to fix this or where I've made an error or wrong assumption?

Comment: Do you want to use `FirstLight` or `First Light` as the first key in the Record?

Comment: Good question, let me quickly check the code and get back to you but I think I'll be using `FirstLight`

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `FirstLight` as my labels are from the i18n files later anyway

Comment: Oh that. `TIMEOFDAY.FirstLight` will give `First Light`. Then you have to change things

Comment: But it also says "Morning" is missing so while I have to fix that, there's another issue

Comment: I added an answer based on your comment here

Comment: As well as doing it the way @Harrison, shows.  Another idea is get rid of your first const, and just convert into a union type of strings `type TIMEOFDAY = "FirstLight" | "Morning".....`, and then add say a caption prop to TIMEOFDAYDATA, you could then just do things like -> `console.log(TIMEOFDAYDATA.Antemeridiem.temperature);`  Currently your adding another level of re-direction for no gain in code readability or performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so based on your comments, you'll want

```js
type TimeOfDayDataRecord = Record<keyof typeof TIMEOFDAY, TimeOfDayData>
```

Where the key for `TimeOfDayDataRecord` is set to a `keyof typeof TIMEOFDAY` ("a key from the type expressed from `TIMEOFDAY`")

```js
export const TIMEOFDAY = {
  FirstLight: 'First Light',
  Morning: 'Morning',
  Antemeridiem: 'Antemeridiem',
  Zenith: 'Zenith',
  Postmeridiem: 'Postmeridiem',
  Evening: 'Evening',
  LastLight: 'Last Light',
  Night: 'Night',
}

type TimeOfDayData = {
  phase: number
  hours: number
  lux: number
  temperature: number
}


type TimeOfDayDataRecord = Record<keyof typeof TIMEOFDAY, TimeOfDayData>

const TIMEOFDAYDATA: TimeOfDayDataRecord = {
  "FirstLight": /*   */ { phase: 1, temperature: 10, hours: 5, lux: 1 },
  "Morning": /*      */ { phase: 2, temperature: 23, hours: 8, lux: 100 },
  "Antemeridiem": /* */ { phase: 3, temperature: 42, hours: 13, lux: 300 },
  "Zenith": /*       */ { phase: 4, temperature: 55, hours: 16, lux: 500 },
  "Postmeridiem": /* */ { phase: 3, temperature: 48, hours: 22, lux: 300 },
  "Evening": /*      */ { phase: 2, temperature: 32, hours: 25, lux: 100 },
  "LastLight": /*    */ { phase: 1, temperature: 15, hours: 30, lux: 1 },
  "Night": /*        */ { phase: 0, temperature: -10, hours: 33, lux: 0 },
}
/*

The type created is:
type TimeOfDayDataRecord = {
    Morning: TimeOfDayData;
    Antemeridiem: TimeOfDayData;
    Zenith: TimeOfDayData;
    Postmeridiem: TimeOfDayData;
    Evening: TimeOfDayData;
    Night: TimeOfDayData;
    FirstLight: TimeOfDayData;
    LastLight: TimeOfDayData;
}

And the Object created is:
{
  "FirstLight": {
    "phase": 1,
    "temperature": 10,
    "hours": 5,
    "lux": 1
  },
  "Morning": {
    "phase": 2,
    "temperature": 23,
    "hours": 8,
    "lux": 100
  },
  "Antemeridiem": {
    "phase": 3,
    "temperature": 42,
    "hours": 13,
    "lux": 300
  },
  "Zenith": {
    "phase": 4,
    "temperature": 55,
    "hours": 16,
    "lux": 500
  },
  "Postmeridiem": {
    "phase": 3,
    "temperature": 48,
    "hours": 22,
    "lux": 300
  },
  "Evening": {
    "phase": 2,
    "temperature": 32,
    "hours": 25,
    "lux": 100
  },
  "LastLight": {
    "phase": 1,
    "temperature": 15,
    "hours": 30,
    "lux": 1
  },
  "Night": {
    "phase": 0,
    "temperature": -10,
    "hours": 33,
    "lux": 0
  }
}
*/
```

You also no longer need to use square brackets `[]` because you no longer need to compute the property.
Missing any from (or added extra properties not already in) `TIMEOFDAY` will throw an error for TypeScript too which is handy

Comment: Personally this makes more sense,  using the value's from the const array doesn't seem correct.   I would even remove the double quotes from the keys, as it then make it look even more enum-ish.. :)   It feels like `[TIMEOFDAY.Postmeridiem]` is for those coming from C# to feel at home, rather than been good practice..

Comment: Yes that true, I forgot I could remove the quotes too

Comment: I made a few more changes and went with a solution inspired by your answer. You are correct that it didn't make a lot of sense to use the `[TIMEOFDAY.Postmeridiem]` notation for the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. There is a small catch.

```
type key = keyof typeof TIMEOFDAY;
```

Here `key` is a type that accepts keys of TIMEOFDAY. You do not want that. You want the values of all these keys in `TIMEOFDAY`.

This can be done using bracket notation easily.

```
type val = typeof TIMEOFDAY[keyof typeof TIMEOFDAY]
```

The whole could should work as below:

```
export const TIMEOFDAY = {
    FirstLight: 'First Light',
    Morning: 'Morning',
    Antemeridiem: 'Antemeridiem',
    Zenith: 'Zenith',
    Postmeridiem: 'Postmeridiem',
    Evening: 'Evening',
    LastLight: 'Last Light',
    Night: 'Night',
};

type TimeOfDayData = {
    phase: number
    hours: number
    lux: number
    temperature: number
}

type TimeOfDayDataRecord = Record<typeof TIMEOFDAY[keyof typeof TIMEOFDAY], TimeOfDayData>

const TIMEOFDAYDATA: TimeOfDayDataRecord = {
    [TIMEOFDAY.FirstLight]: /*   */ { phase: 1, temperature: 10, hours: 5, lux: 1 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Morning]: /*      */ { phase: 2, temperature: 23, hours: 8, lux: 100 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Antemeridiem]: /* */ { phase: 3, temperature: 42, hours: 13, lux: 300 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Zenith]: /*       */ { phase: 4, temperature: 55, hours: 16, lux: 500 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Postmeridiem]: /* */ { phase: 3, temperature: 48, hours: 22, lux: 300 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Evening]: /*      */ { phase: 2, temperature: 32, hours: 25, lux: 100 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.LastLight]: /*    */ { phase: 1, temperature: 15, hours: 30, lux: 1 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Night]: /*        */ { phase: 0, temperature: -10, hours: 33, lux: 0 },
}
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wCoEkCyBRAeQDEARAQQE04BeOAbwCg5m4iBLKdAGTYHMALGAC44Acnad4PATFEAaJixzRkbZLxGjlUVevmLmZZDGABbYFDYATNmc1GT5yzbP6WcAFrBVMfpq8+-G4sAAoQ6E7WtqaaYREWUa4K7ngAbt5qGmJpGXrJLFwAhtx8gppF6HDSgsHMAHKlwmINMvoAvgDcDAwwAJ5gwHAYbOYEAGYkhb2TMIU09AZwYPzFwCLIAK6mAEYWi-wQG5zrW7tQiwA2GyAnO3vujgNQhTBHa3Cbd+dt3X0DQyNgONJtMXoUAErAJBQKzzSHQqwAHj+wAgYyGuEIpEoAG0ANbAXpouAo4nYfDEcgUAC6cgBowmUxmhQAfN0kGhMJjKZRyBgyCJhgyQcz4dBYbRGO4ceSsVSAHQSEoyakiAD0ACoWBq1fQlitUO8AIx0x4WF5vERGgAMdIOR1QIgArHSrjc4Ea4G18swZdzsRR5dpdLxVXBNe5mDq9ctViIAEymsxPC1Qd7xgDMdsOxzgAA5XdcrdbrV6fXA-RSA-KHGYEi5TGGI9G6Pq43AsyTk+bXmmRAAWRNwe25o2dt0iDMlsuLStyyjygJsXxNrWRuAttuGgdJ0wp3vvJ0u4c5x0egBshfdTun3tnsp5gbiMEiDdXG91rdj247u-3lrgfsCxPB0EyHCcO1vcs50feUchDd9I03b90z-HsAIzIcRzPeNjwgm1SzvaUH2rCoYGqGBEKjT8t2NNDngPK1j2wydbTgfCZ2I-0FRaQQqKQmiUJENizQYgCAFobWzUCO3HIs4EIhQ2iAA)

Comment: If you are looking for `First Light` this will work. If that `FirstLight`, then not. In that case you will have to do things differently, will add to lot more code

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems there, first of all, your keys needs to match string in your enum-like object, so no space in Last light and First Light.

Second problem is, that typescript inherits type of

```
export const TIMEOFDAY = {
    FirstLight: 'First Light',
    Morning: 'Morning',
    Antemeridiem: 'Antemeridiem',
    Zenith: 'Zenith',
    Postmeridiem: 'Postmeridiem',
    Evening: 'Evening',
    LastLight: 'Last Light',
    Night: 'Night',
};
```

like

```
const TIMEOFDAY: {
    FirstLight: string;
    Morning: string;
    Antemeridiem: string;
    Zenith: string;
    Postmeridiem: string;
    Evening: string;
    LastLight: string;
    Night: string;
}
```

therefore it doesnt match that key type eighter, fir for this is using `as const` because it makes it readonly.

```
type TimeOfDayData = {
    phase: number
    hours: number
    lux: number
    temperature: number
}
export const TIMEOFDAY = {
    FirstLight: 'FirstLight',
    Morning: 'Morning',
    Antemeridiem: 'Antemeridiem',
    Zenith: 'Zenith',
    Postmeridiem: 'Postmeridiem',
    Evening: 'Evening',
    LastLight: 'LastLight',
    Night: 'Night',
} as const

type TimeOfDayDataRecord = Record<keyof typeof TIMEOFDAY, TimeOfDayData>

const TIMEOFDAYDATA: TimeOfDayDataRecord = {
    [TIMEOFDAY.FirstLight]: /*   */ { phase: 1, temperature: 10, hours: 5, lux: 1 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Morning]: /*      */ { phase: 2, temperature: 23, hours: 8, lux: 100 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Antemeridiem]: /* */ { phase: 3, temperature: 42, hours: 13, lux: 300 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Zenith]: /*       */ { phase: 4, temperature: 55, hours: 16, lux: 500 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Postmeridiem]: /* */ { phase: 3, temperature: 48, hours: 22, lux: 300 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Evening]: /*      */ { phase: 2, temperature: 32, hours: 25, lux: 100 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.LastLight]: /*    */ { phase: 1, temperature: 15, hours: 30, lux: 1 },
    [TIMEOFDAY.Night]: /*        */ { phase: 0, temperature: -10, hours: 33, lux: 0 },
}
```

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKglgWwgeQGYBECGIvE1AXigG8AoKCqMAC0wGcIAuKAOwFcEAjCAJ3MuoB7NjzrN2XXvwoAbNgA9xHbn0pRgEBJB6ZgIpq2VSAvqQjywgnsCgBjQSzo2YASQCyAUWQAxdAEEATUISaShvOFFgABk4AHNqYGYAcnDImPjgJIAaULcrFjgWWOS8ngKi7NC-Fg0kHjgAEzhNZOra3kbmhEq1AC0IAuBqZP7B6h7KAAVBJzrOlqgk6dmOps0Jig8ANwHC4sXt3YqctSj6aLiE5LOndISNqAA5S8TF54zK4yh6OwcnUlIoEgsEQKAw2FwmAAShB7DwGsEYXCGgAeADWEBAglQ6nAEGxsHcXl8gSyIKQaCwOF0mAAfAD7I5nESfP4Av4YH5mPAKeDqXgkVYEUQyGoANquTyswIAOlStxeAF1mAB6ABUlDVKpIVFoDGYAEYybVtLp9IaAAxkoQiMRQACsZLkiigBqgxhOlAlLJJARlpXKsWVUHVagoWp1NHoBgATMbNKa9DxYwBma3CUTMAAcToUlot7s9FG9Ut9MramlWXWDoYjxF10eYafUCd4ZuTzAALHGoDbM67m86mxaCx7QiXiWyZaM4EMaxqw1A6w39VBO-GtG2kwZ7Y7exm7QaAGy5l32keF8eSyey5bAOZrBDzpfa%20tR1fNk1b81rnP723MDGPZDlAKYXmO4rXtKfqHIGz5hsu76xhuiY-imPZ9naMZ7iBBrgUWUATtBMo3BcGTweGr4rgYRotpuOjboae6YcOp6GpekE%20lO7wJBRCFUUhzBWnRqEdlAAC0eHpgBoGDnmUCjjkxhAA)